# How to load website pages from different server?

Tags: nginx, vue.js, reverse-proxy

I'm intending to change my website to a different approach. I have a Wordpress Website and it's applying multiple site architecture. And the homepage is super heavy, other pages are fine. Normally, it took around 5s to load the homepage. I want to convert the homepage to VueJS or NextJS and other pages are still retain as Wordpress.

I'm thinking of using Nginx proxy to load. Anyone had done this approach so far, please give me advice.

Thanks.

Comment: This question isn't really about a programming issue. You're asking for broad advice. Simple google search answers this https://www.google.com/search?q=vuejs+wordpress+api&oq=vuejs+wordpress+api&aqs=chrome..69i57.5107j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will google more ^^!

Answer (score 1):

I think your question doesn’t have a definite answer.

Your problem (5s initial page load) may arise from poorly written code, bad template structure - or from almost anything.

But, if you think that you can speed it up by using a modern frontend framework like Vue, I’d point you towards the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) WordPress has.

Actually you don’t need a frontend framework for that, you could rewrite your template to utilize [AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX) calls (directly to WordPress or the REST API endpoints), and have more control of download/displaying data on your entry page.